# Create Duplicated Tablix Row based on Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating report using SSRS 2016.
My report contains Tablix and each row of it will fit 1 page of paper (pdf output).
I want to add 2 parameters to accept 
 1. RowNumber 
 2. OutputQty.

Let say, my data is

```
ID. | Data
1   | Bird
2   | Cat
3   | Dog
```

If user wants to receive 
 - Bird 1 page
 - Cat 1 page
 - Dog 3 pages (copies)

```
ID. | Data
1   | Bird
2   | Cat
3   | Dog
3   | Dog
3   | Dog
```

How can I achieve that?

[edit] change example data from color to animal

Answer (score 0):

I've not personally done this, but this looks like it could be of some help.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssrs-to-multiple-pdf-based-on-input-parameters

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not want I want. My example may be a little ambiguous but It's not about color.
I want the output (pdf file which is 1 page per 1 tablix row) to have a multiple copies based on parameter. For example I need Row 1 to have 3 copies in pdf.